# smooth holomorphic functions are CR on the boundary?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Is this true that any holomorphic functions in a domain with smooth boundary, and which is smooth on the boundary is a CR function ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

A CR function is by definition annihilated by a (0,1) vector field tangent to the boundary. But any (0,1) tangent vector to the boundary is a limit of (0,1) tangent vectors in the interior (which annihilate the function in the interior.)

Note that in one variable there are no (0,1)-vectors tangent to the boundary so each smooth function on the boundary is CR.